# Mockito: Assertion on output vs Verification

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I have been writing my unit tests and most of the times, I just assert on the output values returned by subject object being unit tested and occasionally I use verify calls to make sure that certain methods either never invoked or invoked certain number of times.

Right now, I am being asked by a code reviewer to add verify calls on each mock I am using, this in addition to the assertion I am having on the output. Do you think, it makes worthwhile to add these verify calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though this is dangerously close to being a pure matter of opinion (and thus off-topic for StackOverflow), you used the [mockito](/questions/tagged/mockito) tag, so I can answer with regard to Mockito's design philosophy as evidenced through blog posts from Mockito's originator Szczepan Faber linked from Mockito's class-level documentation.

Add `verify` calls in one of two cases:

1. It is part of the specified behavior to make or not make the call, as in a wrapper over an RPC layer. In cases like these, the external interaction is an implementation-agnostic requirement of a working system, so it makes sense to check the right number of calls with the right parameters.
2. There is no other user-visible way to determine the state of the object. You could add some, but it might make more design sense to infer the state based on the object's interactions with the environment.

You probably do not need to add `verify` calls in either of these cases:

1. To `verifyNoMoreInteractions` for calls that don't matter or have meaningful side effects (["Should I worry about the unexpected?" blog post](https://monkeyisland.pl/2008/07/12/should-i-worry-about-the-unexpected/) from [Mockito documentation #8](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.11.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#finding_redundant_invocations))
2. To verify methods you've stubbed with non-default results (["Asking and telling" blog link](https://monkeyisland.pl/2008/04/26/asking-and-telling/) from the code block in [Mockito documentation #2](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.11.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#2)), because the test should only produce correct results if the stubbed methods supply the necessary data.

The risk of over-verification here is that a test can become *brittle*, such that a perfectly-reasonable change of implementation results in a failing test (i.e. different methods are called, or not called, or not called in the same order). If a senior code reviewer tells you to add verifications, I'm not going to say you *can't*: It's absolutely a judgment call here, and your reviewer may be thinking extra-defensively with regard to your implementation. However, remember that the point of a test is to *verify that the implementation conforms to the promises*, not that *the implementation looks or works a certain way internally*. If you get too cavalier with your verifications, it might result in test maintenance difficulties later, while getting you no closer to having working code.

As an additional resource, see [Martin Fowler's post "Mocks aren't Stubs"](https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html), which describes the variety of test doubles (fakes, dummies, stubs, mocks) and some of the tradeoffs about using them alongside or instead of classical state-based testing.